# Compute pixels geographical coordinates of a callibrated map

Tags: dictionary, coordinates, projection, mercator

I have some calibrated maps (using MapCalibrator), for which I need to find out the corresponding OSM style tiles.

While I have found some algorithms to calculate the tiles from geographical coordinates (lat/lon), I am stuck at finding out the pixels location (in lat/lon), based on the few calibrated points I have.

For Ex I have a image 3758/5751 pixels, and following calibrated points:

```
- x     y       lon      lat
- 1897  2224    26.3256  46.2311
- 3303  2708    26.43678 46.20419
- 2297  306     26.3577  46.3365
- 2135  4648    26.3423  46.0967
- 1885  1764    26.3236  46.2561
- 2091  2806    26.3386  46.1995
- 3613  2922    26.4604  46.1921
```

How can I compute the loat/lon for an arbitrary pixel?

PS1. The map is a touristic one, from a small enough region (no idea what projection type uses).

PS2. I am coding in Java.. but any hint would be appreciated.

What I have tried is some linear transformation between the calibrated points and each pixel, but the tiles come out somehow a little shifted to the NW (by a few Km judging by the map scale), and depending on which 2 calibrated points I use, the offset is bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The linear transformation was good enough.

The problem was that the geographical coordinates have the origin in the lower left corner, while the pixels in the upper left  corner. (I'd messed up the Y coordinates, and after a sign reversal in another point, the result seemed almost good... but somehow shifted :D )